# md5 password retrieving

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, md5

i made a registration form and an login form.

i used first used `trim()` and then `md5()` to store the password in database.

i used the same to check the password in database in the login form, but for some unknown reason i cant match the md5 password from the login form.

All i want is to retrieve the password from the database.

The problem is when i store it in database and check it in the php myadmin the md5 password is something like `123456789` and when i echo'd it in login form it gives me this `1234567890`. a zero in the end tht zero is creating the problem otherwise the whole md5 password is matched. my database collation is `latin_1_swedish_ci`.

is there any collation problem ?

i hv used varchar value 255 then text etc. but no solution.

is there any problem in the format or structure ?

please help me retrieve the md5 password correctly eliminating the unwanted zero .

```
function login()

    {
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
            if(!$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
                {die (mysql_error());}

            else
            {
                $username = trim($_POST['username']);
                $username = addslashes($_POST['username']);

                $password = trim($_POST['password']);
                $password = md5($_POST['password']);
                echo $password;


                $check_username = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'")or die(mysql_error());
                $check_username2 = mysql_num_rows($check_username);

                if ($check_username2 == 0)
                    {die ("Username and password doesnt exist");}
                else 
                    {
                        $check_pass = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$password."'")or die(mysql_error());
                        $check_pass2 = mysql_num_rows($check_pass); 
                        echo $check_pass2;
                    }


            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
function register()

    {
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            if(!$_POST['first_name'] || !$_POST['last_name'] || !$_POST['username'] || !$_POST['password'])
                {header ("Location:user_registration.php");}

            else
                {
                    $firstname = trim($_POST['first_name']);
                    $firstname = addslashes($_POST['first_name']);
                    $lastname = trim($_POST['last_name']);
                    $lastname = addslashes($_POST['last_name']);
                    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
                    $username = addslashes($_POST['username']);
                    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
                    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

                    connect();

                    if($mysql_check_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE  `username` LIKE  '$username' "))
                        {
                            $check_row = mysql_num_rows($mysql_check_user);
                            if($check_row > 0)
                            die ("username Exist");
                            else 
                                {
                                    $store = mysql_query
                                            ("INSERT INTO `project_upload`.`users` 
                                            (`id`, `fname`, `lname`, `username`, `password`) 
                                     VALUES (NULL, '$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$password')");

                                }
                            if ($store)
                                {echo "You have regstered succesfully. please go to <a href = 'uploads_login.php'>login page</a>";                                          }   
                            else {echo mysql_error();}

                        }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why on Earth did you use `trim()` on a password?

Comment: Could you please post the code you use for retrieving and storing passwords?

Comment: Are you sure that the zero comes from the database and is not echoed by something else in your code?

Comment: If its just a Zero, why not trim it and match ?

Comment: Without any code examples we can only guess what's going wrong, rather then provide an actual solution to your problem. Could you post some of your code along with the question?

Comment: The `trim()` result actually gets thrown away, so this isn't the problem. The second `SELECT` statement in `login()` is searching for a user whose name is `md5($_POST['password'])`, which seems wrong to me. Also, MD5 never returns a 9 or 10-digit string. In short - it's impossible to see what's going on here...

Comment: "retrieve the password from the database" is not a good way to describe what you are doing.  Just saying.

Comment: The problem is your mysql-query, check my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having as i can see it is that you in the beginning of the code for login have something like: `echo $password;` and a few lines after that you have `echo $check_pass_2;` which would result in a string to the browser looking like a 0 is there afterwards. This is because `$check_pass_2` just has a count of how many rows was returned from your mysql query, this is 0 since there's no user with the same username as password. So your real problem is the mysql-query, it checks if there's a user with the same username as the password someone entered, which is strange. Try changing your last query in login.php to:

```
 $check_pass = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE password = '".$password."'") 
 or die(mysql_error());
```

Notice that `username = '".$password."'` was changed to `password = '".$password."'`.
Secondly, you should understand that if you do something like:

```
$pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
$pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
```

Then the $pass variable will just be md5'd without having the trim effects on it, to achieve this you should do:

```
$pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
$pass = md5($pass);
```

But you shouldn't trim your passwords since that's just strange and inconvenient, it doesn't really add anything.

The line where you do this:

```
if($mysql_check_user 
   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE  `username` LIKE  '$username' "))
```

That if-statement is superfluos, since you're just making an assignment, you could remove the if and just let the variable be as it is. Ie:

```
$mysql_check_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE '$username'");
```

Also, try to keep some kind of style when coding, this makes it much easier to read your code. Most code editors have this feature by default, perhaps you need to press TAB on every newline to indent properly, this is a huge help though so do it. Example of how it could look:

```
function register()
{
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        if(!$_POST['first_name'] || 
           !$_POST['last_name'] || 
           !$_POST['username'] || 
           !$_POST['password'])
            header ("Location:user_registration.php");
        else
        {
            $firstname = trim($_POST['first_name']);
            $firstname = addslashes($_POST['first_name']);
            $lastname = trim($_POST['last_name']);
            $lastname = addslashes($_POST['last_name']);
            $username = trim($_POST['username']);
            $username = addslashes($_POST['username']);
            $password = trim($_POST['password']);
            $password = md5($_POST['password']);

            connect();

            if($mysql_check_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE  `username` LIKE  '$username' "))
            {
                $check_row = mysql_num_rows($mysql_check_user);
                if($check_row > 0)
                    die ("username Exist");
                else 
                {
                    $store = mysql_query
                             ("INSERT INTO `project_upload`.`users` 
                             (`id`, `fname`, `lname`, `username`, `password`) 
                             VALUES (NULL, '$firstname', '$lastname', '$username', '$password')");
                }
                if ($store)
                    echo "You have regstered succesfully. please go to <a href = 'uploads_login.php'>login page</a>";                                          
                else 
                    echo mysql_error();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is no option to decrypt the MD5 chars. If you wish to compare, you must convert the input into MD5 string then you can easily compare with the stored values in db.

Comment: I did it sir but didn't get the correct match due to an extended zero in the end of MD5 number for example if md5 conversion is 123456789 i get 1234567890 a zero in the end

Comment: How you check that you are getting "1234567890". Also Have you checked after removing trim() method.

Comment: @Krishnan yes i have tried by removing trim. i stored a username and md5 password by registering. den i looked at the md5 code in php myadmin user table where i hv stored that password. den i used md5 encryption method again in login form to match the password. but when i started getting error that password didnt match. i echoed the md5 converted password in my browser (which i used in login form). i get the exact same md5 encrypted code except an additional zero in the end of the code.